# what does 2miner.com's "hr2" and "rhr" numbers mean?

Tags: external-api, mining-pools

2miner.com's JSON stats returns stuff like

```json
{
    "workers": {
        "Rig1Name": {
            "lastBeat": 1652915927,
            "hr": 29087609,
            "offline": false,
            "hr2": 58983207,
            "rhr": 68940523,
            "sharesValid": 60,
            "sharesInvalid": 0,
            "sharesStale": 0
        },
        "Rig2Name": {
            "lastBeat": 1652916412,
            "hr": 96958697,
            "offline": false,
            "hr2": 138166143,
            "rhr": 138026815,
            "sharesValid": 154,
            "sharesInvalid": 0,
            "sharesStale": 0
        }

    }
}
```

"hr" seems to be current effective hashrate, but what does "hr2" and "rhr" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hr = current hashrate

hr2 = average hashrate

rhr = reported hashrate

Current hashrate - last 30 minutes of work = hr

Average hashrate - last 6 hours = hr2

Reported Hashrate - last sec = rhr

Comment: Thanks! average what though? average last hour? last 6 hours? last 30 days? i know a competing mining pool, ethermine.org, use "average last 6 hours"

Comment: Current hashrate - last 30 minutes of work = hr ||

average hashrate - last 6 hour(s) = hr2

Comment: awesome, can you add the 30 min + 6 hour info to the post?